# RegEx for converting tags to BBCode

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, bbcode

I have a form which takes HTML, converts it to BBCode and stores it in the database.

Most tag renaming is easily handled with a simple switch, however, text alignment is causing me some trouble.

HTML is `<div style="text-align: right;"></div>` and I need to convert to BBcode  [right][/right]

So I can easily do str_replace on the opening tag but for the closing tag I am replacing  but that could be [/left],[/center] or [/right]. I need to know what the opening tag is before I can set it, hence the problem.

I am bad at simple regex so this one is even more difficult.

In logic terms I am trying to do this:

```
$str = str_replace("</div>","$align_value",$str);
```

But I need to know what the opening tag is to set the correct closing tag.

The expected result is it will check what the opening tag is:

```
if($opening_tag = '<div style="text-align: right;">')
{
 $closing_tag = '[/right]';
} else if($opening_tag = '<div style="text-align: center;">')
{
 $closing_tag = '[/center]';
} else if($opening_tag = '<div style="text-align: left;">')
{
 $closing_tag = '[/left]';
} else {
  // Some other div that isn't aligned so do nothing
}
```

But they key is being able to find what the opening tag is first. Any help appreciated

Comment: You should not be using regular expressions for this, you should be using an HTML parser. `<div style="text-align: right">`, `<div class="foo" style="text-align:right">`, `<div style="color:red; text-align: right;">`, `<div data-something="text-align: right">`, etc. How do you expect to deal with all these possibilities?

Comment: There are also libraries to do this for you: https://github.com/vamsiikrishna/html-to-bbcode was the first one I came across.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best idea to solve this problem with regular expressions. However, if you wish to do so, we want to get the attribute value, which I'm guessing that it would be always left, right and center, then collect our element textContents, store it in two capturing groups and then add our desired tags to it, maybe similar to:

```
<.+?:\s+([a-z]+);">(.+?)<\/div>
```

We can also change the `div` closing tag with a more broad expression, if necessary:

```
<.+?:\s+([a-z]+);">(.+?)<\/.+?>
```

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /<.+?:\s+([a-z]+);">(.+?)<\/div>/gm;
const str = `<div style="text-align: right;">Anything you wish here</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Anything you wish here</div>
<div style="text-align: left;">Anything you wish here</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Anything you wish here</div><div style="text-align: right;">Anything you wish here</div>`;
const subst = `[$1]$2[/$1]`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sDP3Hq/1)

#### PHP

```
$re = '/<.+?:\s+([a-z]+);">(.+?)<\/.+?>/m';
$str = '<div style="text-align: right;">Anything you wish here</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Anything you wish here</div>
<div style="text-align: left;">Anything you wish here</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Anything you wish here</div><div style="text-align: right;">Anything you wish here</div>';
$subst = '[$1]$2[/$1]';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sDP3Hq/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

Based on [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol)'s advice in the comment, this method would not work with nested tags.

Comment: `<div style="text-align: right;"><div style="text-align: center;">Nested tags are a problem for your code.</div></div>`

Comment: Yes it would need to work for nested tags also but otherwise the solution was exactly what I was looking for.